# Editing Page Source with a Google Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to make a Chrome extension that will grab the source code like this:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML
```

This may not be the best way though...then change search and replace text in the source....like if the word "cool" is in the page, then replace it with something else and display the modified page to the user. How would I do this?

Also, not just text, I need to edit the source code, not just text shown.

My goal is to edit the page source link, such as style sheets and other sources. I need to change the `https://` -- if the is one -- and replace it with `http://`.

Comment: Can't you just run javascript on the users browser? and modify it that way

Comment: Can i do a find and replace, before the webpage is displayed? My goal is to edit the page source link, such as style sheets and other sources. I need to change the Https:// If the is one, and replace it with Http://

Answer (score 0):

The best way is:

1. Add jquery to your options.html
2. Than use jquery to solve your problems like

   $('#searchfield').val('TEST');
   // and so on...

Hopefully it helps.

PS.: I wrote an chrome-extension as well maybe it could help you to start (https://github.com/marcofrancke/AmazonExtended)

Comment: So, i need to replace the https in the url of the sources, then replace it with http. Before the page loads, so the links will not be https, but http instead.

Answer (score 0):

try http://api.jquery.com/clone/ or `var element = $0;` ( Returns Root Element)

Ex: 
Code to get Tag Name Description:

```
var getElementReference = function() {

    var element = $0;
    var tagName = element.tagName;
    var dictionary = {
        a: "Defines an anchor",
        abbr: "Defines an abbreviation",
        acronym: "Defines an acronym",
        address: "Defines contact information for the authorowner of a document",
        applet: "Deprecated. Defines an embedded applet",
        area: " Defines an area inside an image-map",
        b: "Defines bold text",
        base: " Defines a default address or a default target for all links on a page",
        basefont: " Deprecated. Defines a default font, color, or size for the text in a page",
        bdo: "Defines the text direction",
        big: "Defines big text",
        blockquote: "Defines a long quotation",
        body: "Defines the document's body",
        br: " Defines a single line break",
        button: "Defines a push button",
        caption: "Defines a table caption",
        center: "Deprecated. Defines centered text",
        cite: "Defines a citation",
        code: "Defines computer code text",
        col: " Defines attribute values for one or more columns in a table ",
        colgroup: "Defines a group of columns in a table for formatting",
        dd: "Defines a description of a term in a definition list",
        del: "Defines deleted text",
        dfn: "Defines a definition term",
        dir: "Deprecated. Defines a directory list",
        div: "Defines a section in a document",
        dl: "Defines a definition list",
        dt: "Defines a term (an item) in a definition list",
        em: "Defines emphasized text ",
        fieldset: "Defines a border around elements in a form",
        font: "Deprecated. Defines font, color, and size for text",
        form: "Defines an HTML form for user input",
        frame: "  Defines a window (a frame) in a frameset",
        frameset: "Defines a set of frames",
        h1: " Defines HTML headings",
        h2: " Defines HTML headings",
        h3: " Defines HTML headings",
        h4: " Defines HTML headings",
        h5: " Defines HTML headings",
        h6: " Defines HTML headings",
        head: "Defines information about the document",
        hr: "  Defines a horizontal line",
        html: "Defines an HTML document",
        i: "Defines italic text",
        iframe: "Defines an inline frame",
        img: " Defines an image",
        input: " Defines an input control",
        ins: "Defines inserted text",
        isindex: "Deprecated. Defines a searchable index related to a document",
        kbd: "Defines keyboard text",
        label: "Defines a label for an input element",
        legend: "Defines a caption for a fieldset element",
        li: "Defines a list item",
        link: " Defines the relationship between a document and an external resource",
        map: "Defines an image-map ",
        menu: "Deprecated. Defines a menu list",
        meta: " Defines metadata about an HTML document",
        noframes: "Defines an alternate content for users that do not support frames",
        noscript: "Defines an alternate content for users that do not support client-side scripts",
        object: "Defines an embedded object",
        ol: "Defines an ordered list",
        optgroup: "Defines a group of related options in a select list",
        option: "Defines an option in a select list",
        p: "Defines a paragraph",
        param: " Defines a parameter for an object",
        pre: "Defines preformatted text",
        q: "Defines a short quotation",
        s: "Deprecated. Defines strikethrough text",
        samp: "Defines sample computer code",
        script: "Defines a client-side script",
        select: "Defines a select list (drop-down list)",
        small: "Defines small text",
        span: "Defines a section in a document",
        strike: "Deprecated. Defines strikethrough text",
        strong: "Defines strong text",
        style: "Defines style information for a document",
        sub: "Defines subscripted text",
        sup: "Defines superscripted text",
        table: "Defines a table",
        tbody: "Groups the body content in a table",
        td: "Defines a cell in a table",
        textarea: "Defines a multi-line text input control",
        tfoot: "Groups the footer content in a table",
        th: "Defines a header cell in a table",
        thead: "Groups the header content in a table",
        title: "Defines the title of a document",
        tr: "Defines a row in a table",
        tt: "Defines teletype text",
        u: "Deprecated. Defines underlined text",
        ul: "Defines an unordered list",
        xmp: "Deprecated. Defines preformatted text"
    };

    var result = {
        tag: tagName,
        description: dictionary[tagName.toLowerCase()],
        __proto__: null
    };

    return result;
}
```

Comment: why would the clone help? i am needing to find the https:// in the source link, then change it to http:// ? I am not following you.

Comment: Can you try using chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow.getResources API and edit URL using resource.setContent